# Diff history source code with local

Tags: bitbucket

Bitbucket web site has the diff function. It diffs the previous changes. What I want is to diff any history commit with my local source code, suppose I don't want to commit my local code at this moment as some facts have not decided.

Can we do it? I use Bitbucket/Git and SourceTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can diff "anything" to "anything" but from the command line.
Therefore if you go to the command line, git will be there (because at the end Sourcetree sets up git for you).

You can do "$git diff branch branch" or any specific commit and you'll see the diff.

Edit:

Additionally you can diff your current state against anything:

```
git diff branch (or tagged version)
```

Comment: I meant `diff` **any-commit** with local **uncommit** code. I was not saying `diff` **commit1** with **commit2**. Can we do it?

Comment: I'd unsure. But you can always make a new branch with your uncommited code!